# Host domain name pointer in linux

Tags: fedora, dns, domain

I setup a Linux server and run a command, `host wan ip` in terminal and it shows `... domain name pointer mail.domain.com`.

How do i replace current new `mail.domain.com` to `mail.newdomain.com`?

Comment: what are is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Can you please add more details to your Q? It's difficult to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS works in both directions.

mostly it is used to map a human memorizable name (e.g. `mail.domain.com`) to IP-addresses (e.g. `1.2.3.4`). this is done via so-called `A` records, e.g.:

```
mail.domain.com. IN A  1.2.3.4
```

to change the IP-address that is resolved vrom `mail.domain.com`, you have to have control over the domain `domain.com`. only then you can change that record.

but it also works the other way round, to map IP-addresses to domain names.
IP-addresses are (like domain-names) hierarchical in nature, but (unlike domain-names) the highest-level is on the left side.
mapping works via `PTR` records, using a "pseudo-domain" `in-addr.arpa`
a "reverse-lookup" record for the above example looks like the following (note the reverse ordering of the IP-address)

```
4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa IN PTR mail.domain.com.
```

to change the name that is resolved from the IP-address `1.2.3.4`, you have to have control over the "domain" `4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa`. only then you can change that record.

so in order to change the reverse-lookup, you must find out who is in charge of your IP-range and request that they fix the PTR record.